# How to define edge cutsets in Zimpl?

Tags: linear-programming, scip

- Consider a directed graph `G=(V, A)`, where `V = V_1 \cup V_2` is the set of vertices and `A` is the set of directed arcs.
- Let `\alpha(W, W') = {(u,v) | u \in W \land v \in W'}`. That is the set of arcs leaving from `W` to `W'`.
- For each arc `(u,v) \in A`, there is an associated variable `x_{(u,v)}`
- Now, I want to create a constraint that: `\forall S \subset V: \sum_{(u,v) \in \alpha(V_1, V_2)} x_{(u,v)} \geq 2.`

My question is how can I define the `\alpha` function in Zimpl? From its document (at http://zimpl.zib.de/download/zimpl.pdf), an argument of a function can only be a number or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define alpha as the intersection of A with (W x W'). All of these set operations are available in ZIMPL.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the solution thank to Leon's hint:

```
set PV[] := powerset(V);
set KV   := indexset(PV);
# print out all arcs in \alpha
do forall <k> in KV with card(PV[k]) > 0 do
    print (A inter ((V - PV[k]) * PV[k]));
```